# Replacement pulleys for Shimano Deore XT RD-M739 SGS derailleur (8sp)

Tags: derailleur-rear

Wondering what replacement pulleys I should get for this type of derailleur.

All details of the derailleur can be found here: https://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=4f90a749-6254-4a37-840d-aa0790bd6be7&Enum=108.

It is running an 8sp chain.

Thanks!

Comment: According to this old post ( https://www.retrobike.co.uk/threads/shimano-xt-m739-rear-mech-questions.211627/ ) the derailleur should accept 10-tooth pulleys for 8-speed chains. The OP from that thread mentions the Shimano parts numbers as:
Shimano 53H 9808
Shimano 53Y9807
But those numbers only seem to lead to pulleys for 6/7/8 speed road derailleurs?

Comment: Anything that is same tooth count and has the same sized hole for the bolt/bushing should work.

Comment: Use any 10 tooth pulleys from any similar shimano derailleur. Also 11t usually works fine. Some fancy aluminium ones from china would look nice